# Select a column with condition with other column as it is

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have not searched a lot before asking because I am feeling the search string complicated to write.

I will ask by example instead of description.

I have a table called user_sale

```
id emp_id emp_name emp_location date sales
------------------------------------------------------
1  111    mr.one   A            2013/07/17   5000
2  111    mr.one   C            2013/07/14   6000
3  222    mr.two   B            2013/06/15   5500
```

and so on.

In output I want all field as it is but want emp_location latest within a month.
I am able to get month and year from date. So I can do group by year and month.

expected output:

```
id emp_id emp_name emp_location date sales
------------------------------------------------------
1  111    mr.one   A            2013/07/17   5000
2  111    mr.one   A            2013/07/14   6000
3  222    mr.two   B            2013/06/15   5500
```

One solution is to join with the same table, but since the table contains large data it does not seem like a proper solution.

Comment: You should not be afraid to join in SQL, SQL is designed to joins quickly.

Comment: You forgot: Postgres version, table definition like you get with `\d` in psql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [window function **`first_value()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) to get the "first" of one column (`emp_location`) as defined by another column (`date`), embedded in otherwise unchanged rows:

```
SELECT id, emp_id, emp_name
     , first_value(emp_location) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id
                                       ORDER BY date DESC) AS emp_location
     , date, sales
FROM   user_sale
ORDER  BY id;
```

Assuming that `emp_id` is unique per group as you define it.

Aside: you shouldn't be using `date` ([reserved word in SQL standard](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html)) or `id` (non-descriptive) as column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowing function, like this to get the latest data for each employee:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *,
          row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_name ORDER BY date_sales DESC) AS pos
     FROM user_sale
  ) AS rankem
WHERE pos = 1;
```

I'm not quite clear what exactly you want but I imagine you can join to that sub-query to get what you need.